# DAC Output Noise

Tags: noise, dac

I'm using DAC902 @ clock rate of 40 MSPS. The DAC is generating a 1 MHz sine wave. when I measure the output of the DAC, I get the following noisy sine wave:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what's the reason behind this. I did notice that in the datasheet, they didn't mention a clock rate of 40 MSPS, so I'm not sure if that's the reason behind the problem. To see the datasheet, you can visit the link:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac902.pdf?ts=1603505920654&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Below is a picture of the schematics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! What's *wrong*? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: and: at which of the points in the schematic are you measuring?

Comment: what does it look like once it's been through the necessary reconstruction filter?

Comment: I'm measuring pin 2 of the LM7171 op-amp. There is a lot of noise that is being carried and amplified by the op-amps. I added a better picture to help illustrate my point. I tried to add a 27pf capacitor in parallel with the 1.2k feedback resistor of the first lm7171 op-amp and that actually worked to clean the noise. In any event, I'm not sure, but I don't think the output of the DAC should be that noisy.

Comment: Looks like you have some high frequency noise modulated on your output. An FFT view might give you a clue where it's coming from.

Comment: also: hint: your oscilloscope has a "print screen" functionality (if I remember that series of oscilloscopes correctly, even a dedicated button). That gives better pictures and is easier to use than your smartphone camera....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just eyeballing the ripples on your sine: that is 40 ripples per period of your sine - that's the sampling rate.

You forgot to add a proper *reconstruction filter*, as Neil already pointed out in the comments. You'll want to fresh up your discrete signal theory on why you need that!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My problem is I followed the datasheet blindly. I increased the value of the capacitor C52 and that solved my problem.

Comment: You had to increase that significantly, then, and probably are badly loading the DAC's output, leading to a bad linearity! Your signal will look very bad for sines of other frequencies! Bad idea. But: your large C52 also constitutes low-pass filtering (just not the right kind). You following the datasheet was right: The signal at that point simply isn't *meant* to already be reconstruction-filtered, so it's expected that it doesn't look "clean". Usually, that filtering does happen – later on

Comment: You are right again. I had to increase that cap value up to 1nf to make a noticeable difference. I knew that C52 is not a low pass filter, but the datasheet said that and that didn't make sense to me; why are they saying it's a low pass filter. In any event, the datasheet now makes more sense. They said to add this capacitor if the stepped output of the DAC is causing the op-amp to be slew-rate limited. I take that to mean that they know that the signal will look noisy, and the only reason to smooth out the signal a little is if it's causing your op-amp to be slew-rate limited.

Comment: I have never worked with a DAC before, so that's why I didn't know what the output will look like. I thought that the output would be smooth without the need for any filtering. I'm not sure it's a good idea to keep that noise in the signal for the circuit I'm working on. I might try to add a feedback capacitor to the LM7171 capacitor, and it will filter that noise. I tried that before, and it worked great.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Abdullah C52 together with the source impedance of the DAC  *is* a low-pass filter, of course, but not the kind you want. When working with DACs, you really want to read up on DAC theory, and what a *reconstruction filter* is (I hope you've already done that, now that we've mentioned it four times). It's not hard to understand!

Comment: Yes thank you for the information. I already started reading on how DACs work. I just didn't know about all of that information until you mentioned it. Thank you